# Wireless Xbox 360 controller on Humble Bundle V

Tags: wireless, games, xbox-360, gamepad

I got the Humble Indie Bundle Complete (including Bastion, Lone Survivor, Braid and Super Meat Boy... the whole bundle is excellent).

The fact is that Braid, Super Meat Boy, nor any game in the bundle, has XBox 360 wireless support (it's logical, but disappointing at the same time), nor any kind of gamepad support.

I wanted to know if there is a solution for this conflict, having in mind that I am acctualy a newcomer (I know how to use a terminal and apt-get, though) and everything I've read by now didn't gave me a concrete solution to my predicament.

I tried using xboxdrv in SUDO mode, and get the controller to be recognised and working correctly, but I cannot bind the controllers POV, analog sticks or buttons. I also tried using joy2key, but it's frustrating for me to configure.

I wanted, also, to know if there exist any kind of GUI or at least a guide to use joy2key and saving the templates and configurations for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xboxdrv allows you to do full keyboard and mouse emulation, so it can do everything you need. An example config would look something like this (haven't looked at what keys Braid and SMB use, so you have to change them):

```
[xboxdrv]
ui-clear=true

[ui-buttonmap]
DU=KEY_UP
DD=KEY_DOWN
DL=KEY_LEFT
DR=KEY_RIGHT

A=KEY_ENTER
B=KEY_SPACE
X=KEY_A
Y=KEY_Z

START=KEY_ESC

[ui-axismap]
X1=KEY_LEFT:KEY_RIGHT:12000
Y1=KEY_UP:KEY_DOWN:12000
```

Use it with:

```
sudo xboxdrv -s --config path_to_config.xboxdrv
```

Comment: Is a little bit tricky, but it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

supermeatboy has supported both my classic as well as 360 controllers on 12.04 out of the box - with classic, I had to edit the game configs to get the buttons where I wanted them to be, but changed them back for the 360 controller.  Are you sure your controller is connected / synced correctly?

Comment: supermeatboy works for me 10.04